# How to run identical NetLogo simulations in parallel from R?

Tags: r, netlogo

I want to run multiple instances of a NetLogo model with the same parameters. I'm using the RNetLogo package and following the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968817/running-netlogo-simulation-in-parallel-from-r)

However, when I run my code, the `parSapply` function gives me the following error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :    one node produced an error:
>   unused argument (X[[i]])

I'm totally new to parallel processing so I'm not sure what this refers to as I seem to have options for all of the arguments.

Here is my code:

```
#' load the libraries
#' load the parallel package
library(parallel)
library(RNetLogo)

# detect the number of cores available
processors <- detectCores()
processors

# create a cluster
cl <- makeCluster(processors)
cl

# the initialization function
prepro <- function(dummy, gui, nl.path, model.path) {
  library(RNetLogo)
  NLStart(nl.path, gui = gui, nl.jarname = "netlogo-6.0.4.jar")
  NLLoadModel(model.path)
}

#' the function for the model 
simfun <- function(x) {

 #' the reporters for the model 
 vars <- c("ticks", "who", "g" , "sex", "gm_val")
 agents <- "turtles"
 reporters <- sprintf("map [x -> [%s] of x ] sort %s", vars, agents)
 nlogo_ret <- RNetLogo::NLReport(reporters)

  NLCommand("setup")
  run <-
    NLDoReport(
      x,
      "repeat 1000 [go]",
      c("ticks", reporters),
      as.data.frame = T,
      df.col.names = c("ticks", reporters)
    )
}

# the quit function
postpro <- function(x) {
  NLQuit()
}


# set variables for the start up process
# adapt path appropriate (or set an environment variable NETLOGO_PATH)
gui <- TRUE
nl.path <- "C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.4\\app"
model.path <-
  "\\trout-migration-full-time-matrix.nlogo" # enter the path for your own computer here 

# load NetLogo in each processor/core
invisible(
  parLapply(
    cl,
    1:processors,
    prepro,
    gui = gui,
    nl.path = nl.path,
    model.path = model.path
  )
)
#' the number of 1000 ticks simulations we want to run
#' sampling takes place every 1000th tick
slice <- 10
print(slice)

result.par <- parSapply(cl, slice, simfun)
```

My model is here: [trout-migration-full-time-matrix.nlogo](https://github.com/kanead/trout-migration/blob/master/trout-migration-full-time-matrix.nlogo)

Comment: Please indicate where the problem occurs. Is this in `parLapply` or `parSapply`? Ideally you would prepare a minimal example that would run on any computer. Can you explicitly name all the arguments (e.g. `parLapply(..., fun = prepro, ...)` just to make sure no monkey business is going on?

Comment: Hi, the issue occurs with the parSapply function which I've added now. I've added a link to the full model too. Thanks

Comment: Please format the question properly (e.g. missing quotes) and include enough information in the post so that we're able to rerun the code and reproduce the error.

Comment: Everything should be there now to reproduce the error.